# CSS transition buttons hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 css animate hover buttons on my website.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d72922ff4

When you "hover" over "ÖPPETTIDER" and "KONTAKT" the "NYHETER" background image disappear (animates off to the left).

But I also want "NYHETER" button to disappear when hover the "POPPULÄRA VAROR" button.

CSS

```
#menu-nav li.menu-nav a {
    background:url(images/arrowTest2.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:top right; 
    margin:0 0 15px 0; 
    padding:0 20px 0 0; 
    color:#000; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:33px; 
    width: 95%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    list-style:none;
}
#menu-nav li.nav a {
    background-position:-300px 0;
}
.active{
    background-position:-300px 0;
}
.padding-top{padding-top:30px}
.no-nav{background:none!important;background-position:-300px 0!important;padding:0!important}
```

jQuery,

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($){
    //alert("Hello");
    $("#menu-nav li.menu-nav").each(function(i){
        $(this).addClass('nav').siblings('.active').removeClass('nav');
    });



    $("#menu-nav li.menu-nav").hover(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('nav').siblings().addClass('nav');
        }, function() {
            $(this).addClass('nav').siblings('.active').removeClass('nav');
    //
        }).on('click', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('nav').addClass('active').siblings().addClass('nav').removeClass('active');
    });
    $("#menu-nav li.active").removeClass('nav');

});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle for us to work with? Your website is not loading for me

Comment: HI! the website is now loading..